# Paste entire column into QTableView from Excel

Tags: excel, qt, pyqt, paste, qtableview

I am having an issue pasting into a QTableView from Excel when the user has copied by selecting an entire column in Excel, essentially putting every single row in the selected column, for the entire excel sheet, on the clipboard.  The following is my paste code for QTableView (please note, this is in Python using PyQt but the principle is the same as C++).

```
def paste(self):
        model=self.model()
        pasteString=QtGui.QApplication.clipboard().text()

        rows=pasteString.split('\n')
        numRows=len(rows)
        numCols=rows[0].count('\t')+1

        selectionRanges=self.selectionModel().selection()

        #make sure we only have one selection range and not non-contiguous selections
        if len(selectionRanges)==1:
            topLeftIndex=selectionRanges[0].topLeft()
            selColumn=topLeftIndex.column()
            selRow=topLeftIndex.row()
            if selColumn+numCols>model.columnCount():
                #the number of columns we have to paste, starting at the selected cell, go beyond how many columns exist.
                #insert the amount of columns we need to accomodate the paste
                model.insertColumns(model.columnCount(), numCols-(model.columnCount()-selColumn))

            if selRow+numRows>model.rowCount():
                #the number of rows we have to paste, starting at the selected cell, go beyond how many rows exist.
                #insert the amount of rows we need to accomodate the paste
                model.insertRows(model.rowCount(), numRows-(model.rowCount()-selRow))

            #block signals so that the "dataChanged" signal from setData doesn't update the view for every cell we set
            model.blockSignals(True)  

            for row in xrange(numRows):
                columns=rows[row].split('\t')

                [model.setData(model.createIndex(selRow+row, selColumn+col), QVariant(columns[col])) for col in xrange(len(columns))]

            #unblock the signal and emit dataChangesd ourselves to update all the view at once
            model.blockSignals(False)
            model.dataChanged.emit(topLeftIndex, model.createIndex(selRow+numRows, selColumn+numCols))
```

This all works fine when a user has selected just a bunch of cells in Excel and copied those.  It breaks down when they select an entire column because `pasteString` then becomes upwards of 1048576 characters long (this found by printing pasteString.size() when highlighting a completely empty Excel column by selecting its header and copying).

Is there anyway to get the copied column from the clipboard more efficiently than tab delimited text or something?  Or should I just throw up an error when the size of the string on the clipboard is some arbitrarily large length?

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with QTableView but I had similar experience in VBA Excel; obviously you hit bottom of the sheet. there are 65,536 rows in Excel 97 - 2003 and 1048576 rows in 2007+, it is not arbitrary.

check for the number of rows, any of the 2 values indicate you just went through the entire column without hitting any cell containing a value, hence the column is empty.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain myself well.  Highlighting an entirely empty column was just an example.  If the first cell in the selected column has a single character in it, the length of pasteString grabbed from QClipboard is now 1048577, +1 more than before because of the value in the first cell.

Comment: ok, I misunderstood the problem; so any `pasteString.size() >= 1048576` indicates an entire column has been selected. then i would parse it like an array and discard all the empties above and below the relevant area; (between the first and last hit with content); this should easily eliminate a million rows